# Bing Maps REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, bing-maps

```
$.getJSON('http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/34.00689078318612,35.648735554695115?key=mykey&o=json', function () {
    alert('works!');
});
```

so this doesn't reach the `alert();` and the request is "RED" in firebug console with no additional errors.

However just pasting the URL in the browser window returns valid JSON.

I am running out of ideas to try for this... What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this..

```
$.getJSON('http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/34.00689078318612,35.648735554695115?key=mykey&o=json&jsonp=?', function () {
  alert('works!');
});
```

Your code is failing due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You must use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to bypass this.

Comment: It doesn't work and returns this in the console: `invalid label
[Break On This Error]  

{"authenticationResultCode":"ValidCredentials","brandLogoUri":"http:\/\/dev.virt...

34.006...4989340 (line 1, col 1)
 
` could you explain why the callback=? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's because you have to authenticate with the service before using it. The `callback=?`specifies where the server should send it's response to. You can find more information in the JSONP link I provided.

Comment: I am not getting a 401. I've just replaced my real api key with `mykey` here. :)

Comment: Thanks again, but now it sais `invalid label
[Break On This Error]  

{"authenticationResultCode":"ValidCredentials","brandLogoUri":"http:\/\/dev.virt...

34.006...5876216 (line 1, col 1)
 ` and it points to the " in `{"auth..`

Comment: @user1027620 Could you try taking out `o=json` and trying again?

Comment: Exact same error in console. - Would you like me to share the API Key ?

Comment: @user1027620 If you'd like to e-mail me it at me-at-achurch-dot-me I'll take a look at it

Comment: Thanks alot, I've just sent you an e-mail.